# Flowtype: indexer property is missing in

Tags: flowtype

Given the following code:

```
/* @flow */
interface IDefaultSettings {
  Drivers?: {},
  Options?: {}
}

const defaultSettings: IDefaultSettings = {
  Drivers: {},
  Options: {}
}

const settings: IDefaultSettings = {};

mergeSettings(settings);

function mergeSettings(settings: IDefaultSettings) {
  for (const [key, setting] of Object.entries(defaultSettings)) {
    switch(key) {
      case 'Drivers':
      case 'Options':
        settings[key] = setting;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Place above code in the [Flow playgound](https://flow.org/try/) to try this out.

I'm receiving this lint error, and unable to solve: `` "Cannot assign `setting` to `settings[key]` because an indexer property is missing in `IDefaultSettings` [1]." ``

Why would the use of `key` need an indexer prop in the interface, `IDefaultSettings`, when this code is pulling `key` from an object with a known interface - I mean, what else could `key` be? Both objects, `defaultSettings` & `settings` are of the same type/structure, `IDefaultSettings`.

Help please & thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've chosen to use `interface` over `type`, although its not the specific reason for the problem.  It does mean that flow can't determine what property names are valid.  Note that flow isn't very good at this, but its partly due to the fact it's a static type checker, so anything in a variable can't be comprehensively compared.

If we switch to `type` we get rid of the `indexer property` error, but introduce a new one, which is that the return type from `Object.entries` is a tuple where the value is of type `mixed`.

Your `IDefaultSettings` has two keys with object values, so flow balks at the idea they could be something else.  A solution, although a bit of hack, is to cast the value via `any`.  Or alternatively, use the `$FlowFixMe` comment syntax and document why your muting the error.

```
type IDefaultSettings = {
  Drivers?: {},
  Options?: {}
}

const defaultSettings: IDefaultSettings = {
  Drivers: {},
  Options: {}
}

const settings: IDefaultSettings = {};

mergeSettings(settings);

function mergeSettings(settings: IDefaultSettings) {
  for (const [key, setting] of Object.entries(defaultSettings)) {
    switch(key) {
      case 'Drivers':
      case 'Options':
        settings[key] = (setting: any);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAkgIhAZgQwK4BtgGULGASwDsBzAZygF4oBvAKCigG1lCQBdALigFt8APCABNaAehEM4AJ3wA3CJNIB+LtQC+AGlHioAeTAEA9oSUrVtM7QDGR0sCiCkaTDjxEyXeI4zZcBEuSo6CWk5BVNNBj1DY1NzWisbO1JfN1IPBBRvFz8yShpVAG547nliCGzUgApk138ASiLaRFRCS2ieUvKU-2ru91gMpx9asjqaeihEA0koSutjO0YAawgQdSganLYoA0RdACMAKwg2gDoIQmBpCFJKh0znPtI6saCGDYB3fGBLAAtKlYgV4Td5QSzIZJQADkUlk8lIUI4IPe4MhUKi+BsiORoM2qWWq22VDxJCKoNB+0kEGQSzJ7zMDDMqiAA))

Comment: For those curious, the `Object.entries` returning `mixed` I believe is very similar to this issue where `Object.values` returns `mixed`. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2221